How to import private env variables when code is running on server and public env if running on a client
The problem:
I have a very similar problem as this question, except I want to use the sveltekit dynamic variables instead of vite.
I have an api client ApiClient.ts. I would like to use this ApiClient both on the client-side and on server-side for server side rendering.
I have both sveltekit and api running in the same kubernetes cluster, so I would like to make calls from the server-side directly to http://api:8080 and calls from client-side to https://my-url.com.
I have the INTERNAL_API_URL stored inside private environment and PUBLIC_API_URL in public environemnt.
The question:
Can I conditionally import public environment when running on client and private when running on server environment?
Something like this:
// ApiClient.ts
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    import { env as publicEnv } from '$env/dynamic/public'
} else {
    import { env as privateEnv } from '$env/dynamic/private'
}

// ...


You can't really import private env in code, that can be imported on client, so there are couple of options:

put local URL in public env and use if (browser) to get correct URL
always call some +page.server.ts endpoint, which would just act as proxy
always call external api
configure local DNS on cluster to point my-url.com to locally running API and dynamically use https only when in browser (not sure, how it can be configured in kubernetes)

